# placeholder variable for a UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, variables

I know that I can do this:

```
switch (imageNumber) {
     case 1: image1.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"]]; break;
     case 2: image2.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"]]; break;
     case 3: image3.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"]]; break;
     case 4: image4.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"]]; break;
}
```

I want to be more efficient in my code, so I am wondering if there is a way to do it like this:

```
switch (imageNumber) {
     case 1: //somehow set image1 as the imageView I want used
     case 2: //somehow set image2 as the imageView I want used
     case 3: //somehow set image3 as the imageView I want used
     case 4: //somehow set image4 as the imageView I want used
}
imageWhicheverWasSet.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"]];
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second code snippet you pasted yourself is actually very close to a solution. You just need to set `UIImageView *imageToChange;` as instance variable and then do:

```
imageToChange.image = nil; // will clear the image on last selected image view
// if you don't need that, just remove that line and leave others
switch (imageNumber) {
    case 1: imageToChange = image1; break;
    case 2: imageToChange = image2; break;
    case 3: imageToChange = image3; break;
    case 4: imageToChange = image4; break;
}
imageToChange.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"]];
```

Comment: I assume you meant image1..image2..image3.

Comment: Of course, fixed that just as you were typing your comment :)

Comment: This solution actually works great for the app I'm currently working on, because I am not doing anything additional with the image beyond this. But if I wanted to later set image2.hidden = YES; or change the image in image2, I'm not sure this code would do the job because the image2 UIImageView isn't being changed, it's this new imageToChange that is getting the image. I thought maybe there was some way akin to #define kImageToChange where kImageToChange isn't a UIImageView of its own, but just a placeholder variable so when I set kImageToChange.image it would actually be setting image2.image

Comment: That's exactly what happens here. imageToChange stores a pointer to the image view you want and when you change imageToChange, you actually change that image view instead.

Comment: I just tested this... I have imageToChange = image1; imageToChange.image = [UIImage setimage....]; and then later on I tried image1.image = [UIImage setimage to different image]; but image1 didn't change because image1 doesn't exist.... it's imageToChange which exists

Comment: maybe this is the issue... I am adding these images to the view programmatically, using [self.view addSubview:imageToChange];    - maybe if I wasn't doing this then your pointer trick would work, but as it is, I can't change image1 later because image1 doesn't exist when I use imageToChange in its place

Comment: Yeah, that's why it doesn't work. You should add them all to the view as subviews and then call the code I gave you. Or maybe if you described what you want to do I could give you a better solution because what you are doing now seems very messy.

Comment: Alright - I added them all to the view and this pointer code works perfectly. As you read in my question, I wasn't having an issue doing what I wanted, but I was just hoping to learn something new that might help me write more efficient code. Using a new UIImageView as a pointer seems like a good tool to have learned and that I'll now be able to use when needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could put the UIImageViews in an array, then use the index to select the correct one.  Not sure this would be useful unless you had a lot more UIImageViews to deal with.

```
NSArray* imageViews = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: image1, image2, image3, image4, nil];

UIImageView* theImage = [imageViews objectAtIndex: imageNumber-1];
UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"]];
```

You'd want to validate the `imageNumber` to make sure it was within range.

Answer (score 0):

How about --

```
UIImage* theImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"]];
switch ...
    case 1:image1.image = theImage; break;
    case 2:...
```

You could also do --

```
MyImageType* tempImageObj = nil;
switch ... {
    case 1:tempImageObj = &image1; break; // Or just image1, if ".image" is a property, not a field
    case 2:...
}
tempImageObj ->image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"imageName" ofType:@"jpg"]];  // Or "." instead of "->" if property.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way could be to use an array

```
UIImageView *iv[] = {
  image1,
  image2,
  image3,
  image4,
};
if (imageNumber>=0 && imageNumber<4) 
  iv[imageNumber].image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                           pathForResource:@"imageName" 
                                                    ofType:@"jpg"]]
```